# Google sign-in button not working after my state(angularJS) changes from another page back to login page

Tags: angularjs

could someone help me about google button Sign-in problem(I use gapi)? I use onload callback when I refresh my login page. And it's defined and all worked fine. But after login, I use stateProvider to change to another page, but the problem is when I returned to login, by using $state.go('login'). The google sign in button cannot work if I click it

Comment: can you added a little more code?  see [ask]

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module("app").controller('LoginCtrl',function($state,$scope,googleService) {
   
  
    window.loadGapi = function() {
        
        gapi.load('auth2', function() {
            
            auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
               client_id: googleService.googleSSOClientId,
               fetch_basic_profile: true,
               scope: 'profile' 
            });
            
            var ele = document.getElementById('customBtn');
            var clickAttached = false;
            
            if (!clickAttached) {
                 auth2.attachClickHandler(ele,{},function(googleUser) {
                 onSignIn(googleUser);
              },function(error) {
                 console.log(error);
              });
                
              clickAttached = true;
            }
           
            
        });
                
    };
    
    function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        
        
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        var response = googleUser.getAuthResponse();
        
        document.getElementById('name').innerText = "Signed in: " +
        profile.getName();
        
        // notify angular update, enable two-way binding.
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.isSignIn = true;
        });
        
        // do further authentication with backend server
        
        
        $state.go('googleSignUp', { email: profile.getEmail(), name: profile.getName(), id_token: response.id_token });
        
        var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
        auth2.signOut();
        
    
    }
    
    console.log($scope);
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<!--Login-->
 <div ng-if="!isMobilePhone">
  <button class="g-sign-in-button" id="g-button" >
   <span>SIGN IN WITH GOOGLE</span>
   <i class="g-icon"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="login-or">
   <hr class="or-line or-line-left"/>&nbsp&nbspor&nbsp&nbsp<hr class="or-line or-line-right"/>
  </div>
  <form name="formData.loginForm" novalidate
              ui-enter="login(user)">
   <p>
    <!--Name-->
    <input type="text"
        name="username"
        placeholder="name"
        ng-model="user.name"
        autocapitalize="off"
                       ui-required
        ui-auto-focus />
   </p>

   <p>
    <!--Password-->
    <input type="password"
        name="password"
        placeholder="password"
        ng-model="user.password"
        ui-required/>
   </p>
   <!--Remember Me-->
   <p id="rememberme">
    REMEMBER ME
    <input type="checkbox"
        ng-model="rememberme.value" />
   </p>
  
  </form>
  
  <!--Login Button-->
  <p>
   <button ng-click="login(user)"
     class="purple-button"
     ng-class="{ disabled: formData.loginForm.$invalid }"
     id="log-in-button">

    <span>Log in</span>
    <i class="right-arrow-icon"></i>
   </button>
  </p>

  <!--Register Button-->
  <p>
   <button ng-click="register()"
     class="blue-button"
     id="register-button">

    <span>Start New Account</span>
    <i class="plus-icon"></i>
   </button>
  </p>
  

 <!-- loadGAPI:onload callback-->
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=loadGAPI" defer async></script>
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
 <!-- below is another html page, register, and now I want to
 cancel, so the state turns back to login, wich is the above html-->
      
<form name="formData.registerStudentForm">
 
 <input type="text"
     name="firstName"
     ng-model="formData.student.firstName"
     placeholder="first"
     required  />

 <input type="text"
     name="lastName"
     ng-model="formData.student.lastName"
     placeholder="last"
     required/>
     
 <input type="text"
     name="username"
     ng-model="formData.student.username"
     placeholder="username"
     required/>
     
 <input type="text"
     name="invitationCode"
     ng-model="formData.student.invitationCode"
     placeholder="invitation code"
     required/>

 
    
 <button ng-click="registerStudent(formData.student)"
   class="purple-button"
   ng-class="{ disabled: formData.registerStudentForm.$invalid }">

  <span>Register</span>
  <i class="right-arrow-icon"></i>
 </button>

 <div class="cancel-button">
  <a ui-sref="login()">Cancel</a>
 </div>

</form>
```

Comment: this is main code for google SSO sign in, and after I turn back to my login page, I could only click google Sign in button actively through refreshing page, not by state change. That's my puzzle currently!